# Center Content of Bootstrap Navigation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am trying to center the content of my navigation which uses bootstrap 3.
I have tried a number of suggested solutions from similar questions like the css below, but alas no joy.

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar .navbar-nav {
        display: inline-block;
        float: none;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    .navbar .navbar-collapse {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">     
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a href="/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="/">Mr. Postman</a></li>
  <li><a href="/profile"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootply is a great place to find Bootstrap examples for stuff like this.

http://www.bootply.com/Q7pzI4ddjW

CSS:

```
@media(min-width:768px) {
    .center-nav{
        float: none;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .center-nav > li{
        float: none;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav center-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the .navbar-collapse from your css:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar .navbar-nav {
        display: inline-block;
        float: none;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    .navbar {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```